# JBoss DefaultDS -- To Change? Or Not To Change?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jboss, datasource

We're getting ready to deploy our JavaEE application on JBoss 5.1.  It will be hosted on Amazon EC2 (CentOS 5.x, etc.).  We're moving forward with a clustered solution with 2 app servers.  My question is, how do we handle the DefaultDS datasource that JBoss deploys?  I know that, by default, it uses an embedded database.  Is there any reason why you would configure it to an external database?  We've run through the exercise of changing it to use PostgreSQL.  What are the pros/cons of this type of setup?  If we go with this setup, should each JBoss server have its own database on the PostgreSQL server?  Or should they share the same database?

I'm curious to hear any rationale behind your opinions on the matter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [says](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/Using_other_Databases.html):

> Having a database included with JBossAS is very convenient for running the server and examples out-of-the-box. However, this database is not a production quality database and as such should not be used with enterprise-class deployments. As a consequence of this JBoss Support does not provide any official support for Hypersonic.

That is not a platitude, it is very serious. Things can go wrong (bad things) especially if the file size grows too much. I have had that database corrupt on me seriously and it is not fun to have production down dealing with it.

I didn't set up clustering, but I think it depends on what you are doing on the server. You don't want the same message consumed twice, and those kind of things. So that would need to be investigated.